# Separate instances of custom class have the same values as each other

Tags: ios, objective-c, instance-variables

I have 4 objects of my Color class which I initialized like this:

```
Color *orange = [[[Color alloc] init] initWithRed:255.0 andGreen:128.0 andBlue:0.0];
Color *purple = [[[Color alloc] init] initWithRed:255.0 andGreen:0.0 andBlue:127.0];
Color *cyan = [[[Color alloc] init] initWithRed:204.0 andGreen:0.0 andBlue:102.0];
Color *violet = [[[Color alloc] init] initWithRed:127.0 andGreen:0.0 andBlue:255.0];
```

Those colors are stored in an array:

```
colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:orange, purple, cyan, violet, nil];
```

Later I'm giving a button a background color like this:

```
button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: ([([colors objectAtIndex: 0]) getRed]/255.0)
                            green:([([colors objectAtIndex: 0]) getGreen]/255.0)
                            blue:([([colors objectAtIndex: 0]) getBlue]/255.9) alpha:1];
```

My problem now is that even though the color at index 0 is orange the color of the button is violet. If I remove violet from the array nothing changes but when I remove the Color violet the button gets cyan.

What causes this strange behavior? Or am I doing something wrong?

**Update**

This is my Color class:

```
double Red;
double Green;
double Blue;


- (id)initWithRed:(double) red andGreen:(double) green andBlue:(double) blue {
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setRed:red];
        [self setGreen:green];
        [self setBlue:blue];

    }
    return self;
}



- (void) setRed:(double) red {
    Red = red;
}

- (void) setGreen:(double) green {
    Green = green;
}

- (void) setBlue:(double) blue {
    Blue = blue;
}

- (double) getRed {
    return Red;
}

- (double) getGreen {
    return Green;
}

- (double) getBlue {
    return Blue;
}
```

Comment: please show the code of your `Color` class.

Comment: Why do you have a custom color class?

Comment: @Avi Because I want to save custom colors.

Comment: There is one `init` too much: `Color *orange = [[Color alloc] initWithRed:255.0 andGreen:128.0 andBlue:0.0];` respectively.

Comment: `UIColor` conforms to `NSCoding`.  How are you saving such that that is insufficient?

Comment: BTW, I'm not trying to be a jerk.  It's just often the Foundation classes provide the functionality you think you need a custom class for, and it's always better to use them when you can.

Comment: @Avi Somehow I didn't think of that haha. Is it possible to get the red, green and blue value?

Comment: Sure.  Check the documentation for `UIColor`.  The method you'll want is `-[UIColor getRed:green:blue:alpha]`.  If that's too cumbersome, create a category to implement individual getters.

Comment: @Avi Ok thanks I'm trying this but I think I'll still have the same problem. Do you know what could be wrong with my code now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three variables a you intend to be *instance* variables have been declared at the outermost level and so are *global* variables, i.e. they are shared by every instance. Therefore the color you are getting is the last one you created, regardless of which instance you use.

To declare instance variables place them in braces at the start of the class:

```
@implementation Color : NSObject
{
    double red;
    double green;
    double blue;
}

// methods...

@end
```

You've also called two `init` methods per object, only call one, e.g.:

```
Color *cyan = [[Color alloc] initWithRed:204.0 andGreen:0.0 andBlue:102.0];
```

HTH